# Collect_list doesn't work on partial aggregates

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

For a Spark Structured Streaming dataframe, collect_list throws an error:

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 1024)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Collect cannot be used in partial aggregations.

I have the following code:

```
df.withColumn("RealValue", expr("(Class, Value)"))
    .groupBy("Code", "Origin", "Destination", "PoS", "Date")
    .agg(collect_list("RealValue").as("ValueSeq"))
    .drop("Value")
```

Where df is a streaming dataframe.

The schema is as follows:

```
val schema = new StructType(Array(
  StructField("Code", StringType),
  StructField("Origin", StringType),
  StructField("Destination", StringType),
  StructField("Date", StringType),
  StructField("PoS", StringType),
  StructField("Class", StringType),
  StructField("Value", StringType)
))
```

How do I overcome this?Is there any alternate way of doing this which will work for a Streaming Dataframe?

Comment: Please provide sample input output data for your code to understand the use of groupBy agg and collect_list functions. 
Also provide the schema of the df to better understand the function you are trying to achieve.

Comment: have mentioned schema

Comment: @ac Any solutions?

Comment: @HaoWang Nope, we switched to Spark Streaming due to this shortcoming. Hopefully, they will rectify soon